# Spring Boot 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT redirect not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The following code is working as expected without any issue in Spring Boot 1.5.3 but not in `2.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.

Can any one tell me how to call redirect in Spring Boot 2.0.0?

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
public class SpringBootExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO: Auto-generated method stub
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExampleApplication.class, args); 
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String forawar(Model model) {
    // Validate before authentication
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // httpSecurity.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/validateUser").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/loginError")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashBoardHome")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
            .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: Don't use SNAPSHOTs of libraries if you're not absolutely sure of what you are doing.

Comment: I moved your problem statement before your code block. It's usually easier to digest code with some context. See [ask] for details.